Globally changing arrow-style in chemformula
I managed to use arrow-style within a specific \ch reaction, as shown below in the MWE (following the examples in the manual, section 9.3). However, I'd like to globally change the arrow-style and possibly other properties, to use it in all my reactions. Is it possible?
I found this question, but unfortunately the \chemsetup[chemformula]{arrow-style={}} in the preamble gives me an error.
MWE:
\documentclass[multi=my,border=5]{standalone}
%,convert={density=300,outext=.png}

\usepackage{chemmacros, chemformula}
%\chemsetup[chemformula]{arrow-style={line width=2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{my}
$\begin{aligned}
\ch[arrow-style={line width=1}]{CH4 + Ni &-> Ni-CH2 + H2} \\
\ch{H2O + Ni-CH2 &-> Ni-CHOH + H2} \\
\ch{Ni-CHOH &-> Ni-CO + H2} \\
\ch{Ni-CO &-> Ni + CO}
\end{aligned}$
\end{my}
\end{document}

Which works on my computer, but if I uncomment the \chemsetup[chemformula]{arrow-style={line width=2}} line, it gives me an error.
I'm using MikTeX with TexMaker, all up to date.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

You can do
\setchemformula{arrow-style={line width=2}}

Alternatively, if you want to use \chemsetup you need to set formula={chemformula} before using \chemsetup[chemformula], and use another pair of braces to protect line width=2:
\chemsetup{formula={chemformula}}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{arrow-style={{line width=2}}}

Example:
\documentclass[multi=my,border=5]{standalone}
%,convert={density=300,outext=.png}

\usepackage{chemmacros, chemformula}
\chemsetup{formula={chemformula}}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{arrow-style={{line width=2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{my}
$\begin{aligned}
\ch[arrow-style={line width=1}]{CH4 + Ni &-> Ni-CH2 + H2} \\
\ch{H2O + Ni-CH2 &-> Ni-CHOH + H2} \\
\ch{Ni-CHOH &-> Ni-CO + H2} \\
\ch{Ni-CO &-> Ni + CO}
\end{aligned}$
\end{my}
\end{document}


